# Change the opacity of all elements in webpage by running chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, console, element, opacity

I have tried this but it returns error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined)

```
console.dir(document.getElementsByTagName("*").style.opacity="0.5");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("*")` returns an array of elements. You can't access the style of all those elements at the same time using `elements.style`.

You can set the style for the first element (which should be the root element) like this:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0].style.opacity = 0.5
```

This will affect the root element and all its child elements.